# React App deploying but not running in heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

Thank you in advance for any help with this issue, i have been trying to solve it for some hours now...

I have created a react app with create-react-app and it's running fine in the local server, deployed it to heroku and it deployed sucessfully, but it does not open. 
When i do heroku logs --tail i get the bellow errors:

```
2020-04-23T15:32:00.547380+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.16.17.130/
2020-04-23T15:32:00.547959+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-04-23T15:32:00.548051+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-04-23T15:32:00.548120+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-04-23T15:32:00.548312+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-04-23T15:32:00.548312+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-23T15:32:00.680072+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-23T15:32:01.946329+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=portfolio-carlosamorim.herokuapp.com request_id=3c71f08a-4492-40b7-bb6c-82055d05f0bd fwd="89.153.213.119" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-23T15:32:02.587450+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=portfolio-carlosamorim.herokuapp.com request_id=3a20431f-789e-4da8-a151-438205b055e9 fwd="89.153.213.119" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-23T15:33:23.144950+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=portfolio-carlosamorim.herokuapp.com request_id=d043557d-ed3f-474a-ba84-0d14c2ac2696 fwd="89.153.213.119" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-23T15:33:23.414482+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=portfolio-carlosamorim.herokuapp.com request_id=f612d864-2e2e-4669-a33d-9b5edb23732d fwd="89.153.213.119" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My package.json :

https://github.com/CarlosAmorimProjects/portfolio/blob/master/package.json

Anyone experienced and solved the same issue ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Update :

I was able to deploy it and it's running at Vercel.com, i used buildpack create-react-app and it's working perfectly, i cannot apply that same builpack on heroku.
I suspect the problem is related to that.

Answer (score 0):

The default buildpack when deploying is that of node.js. You needed to use the create-react-app buildpack (as seen below).

```
heroku create $APP_NAME --buildpack mars/create-react-app
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

helpfull link: https://dev.to/webdevraj/deploy-a-react-app-on-heroku-the-right-way-5efo

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Searched for that info but couldn't find it.